# USB drive - cp: cannot create regular file, Read-only file system

Tags: permissions, usb-drive, cp

I am able to copy files from a USB flash drive, but I cannot get the data (files) into the flash drive. It is showing:

```
cp: cannot create regular file `PENDRIVE/12_angrymen.avi': Read-only file system
```

Please suggest how to copy files from my system to the flash drive. The permissions of the flash drive are:

```
drwx------  3 santhosh santhosh 2048 Jan  1  1970 PENDRIVE/**
```

I also can't change the flash drive's permissions. Please help me out.

Comment: What is the output of `mount | grep '^/'`?

Answer (score -1):

IF its a sd card look on the left side of the card there is a little switch to change it from read only so you can also write to it.